# PHP - using str_replace in a foreach from a file isn't working

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
$conn = //Mysqli connection here
$query = '';
$dbPrefix = 'hat'
$sqlFile = file(ROOTPATH."docs/db.sql");
$sqlFields = file(ROOTPATH."docs/sqlfields.txt");

foreach ($sqlFile as $line) {
  $startWith = substr(trim($line), 0, 2);
  $endWith = substr(trim($line), -1 ,1);
    if (empty($line) || $startWith == '--' || $startWith == '/*' || $startWith == '//') {
          continue;
  }
  foreach ($sqlFields as $field) {
    $line = str_replace($field, $dbPrefix.'_'.$field, $line);
  }
  echo $line;
    $query = $query . $line;
    if ($endWith == ';') {
        mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('<div class="error-response sql-import-response">Problem in executing the SQL query <b>' . $query. '</b></div>');
        $query= '';
    }
}
```

This function essentially takes an sql file (docs/db.sql) and prepares to execute it as a query. The SQL file contains a few "CREATE TABLE" statements that are valid and execute correctly. The table names in the file are "users" and "groups" (so far).

The function also grabs a file (docs/sqlfields.txt) and the `foreach ($sqlFields as $field)` should str_replace anything from the file into the $line variable. The sqlfields.txt just simply is:

```
users
groups
```

(for now).

The str_replace is intended to concatenate the $dbPrefix and the table field name whenever it finds $field.

So the code grabs the db.sql file, and splits the lines of the file into their own foreach variable `$line`. The very first line would be `CREATE TABLE users (`. The second foreach should look for any instance of `users` first (since it's the first in the sqlfields.txt file), and replace $field (`users`) with `hat_users` (`$dbPrefix.'_'.$field`).

However, nothing is replaced. The foreach is executed. If I stick a `echo $field;` in the second foreach block the code executes and `users groups` prints before each `$line`.

I've also tried an `if strpos($line,$field) !== False {` in there and a debug echo and that doesn't even work, so I'm puzzled as to what I'm missing.

PHP version is 7.4

Any help you can provide would be terrific. Thanks.

Comment: Concatenate would use `.=` in this line `$line .= str_replace($field, $dbPrefix.'_'.$field, $line);`

Comment: `file` does not strip the line endings when reading the field. You're probably trying to replace `users\n` and not just `users`. Add a `trim` before replacing (or `array_map('trim', file(....));` when reading in `sqlfields.txt`

Comment: or use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag with your `file()` call: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file

Comment: The trim() or FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES works just fine. Thanks!